# How can I access 'spring.application.name' when defined in bootstrap.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have the following spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE sample app

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And I have the following configuration defined in bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.application.name=sample-app
```

When run it I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.name' in string value "${spring.application.name}"
```

Any hint on why it fails to inject 'spring.application.name'? 
Need to define it there to support other spring boot cloud.

Comment: Something else is wrong in this app. If you put it in `bootstrap.properties` and you effectively do use spring cloud, it will be available. My best guess is that `bootstrap.properties` is ignored altogether in your app. Maybe you have the cloud deps but you're not using it?

Comment: Yup, you are right. I was planning to use spring-cloud but after reading your comment realized that I was not using it yet! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first answer is correct. The default properties file is application.properties or application.yml.

The bootstrap file is properly for Spring Cloud.

See http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_the_bootstrap_application_context

If you are using spring cloud, and the bootstrap file is not working, you need to enable the "cloud" Spring profile.

For example using:

```
./gradlew -Dspring.profiles.active=cloud bootrun
```

or

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=cloud
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, if you don't specify any properties source, spring boot will lookup for your property in the file `application.properties`. Therefore, you should rename your property file to that default name or manually specify a properties source for your bootstrap.properties